# How to deploy docker container to kubernetes?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, kubernetes, deployment, containers

I am trying to learn docker and kubernetes. We can say that I am a beginner. I download containers via docker. I want to deploy three of these containers to kubernetes. How can I do this?

> docker images

```
REPOSITORY                    TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
nginx                         latest    2b7d6430f78d   11 days ago     142MB
ubuntu                        latest    df5de72bdb3b   4 weeks ago     77.8MB
busybox                       latest    7a80323521cc   5 weeks ago     1.24MB
gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase   v0.0.33   b7ab23e98277   5 weeks ago     1.14GB
fedora                        latest    98ffdbffd207   3 months ago    163MB
hello-world                   latest    feb5d9fea6a5   11 months ago   13.3kB
```

Comment: At minimum, you will need to create a [Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/)

Comment: As @Tam described, you need to create a Pod. A pod is consists of one or more containers. They are units of deployment that can be scheduled and managed.
Check this link https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a yaml file that contains this configuration for the nginx image:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx:1.14.2
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
```

To create the pod, run the following command

```
kubectl apply -f pathToYourYamlFile
```

Comment: Should I do this for all container?

Comment: Yes you need to do that for all the containers, because for each containers you need to specify its specific ports, volumes, network ...

Comment: and according to what shall I determine containerPort? can I choose a random number?

Comment: According to the container that you are deploying, for example for nginx the default port is 80. Using the containerPort config you are defining the port on which app can be reached out inside the container

Comment: oh okay I create port. What should I do next to deploy container?

Comment: Use this command: kubectl apply -f pathToYourYamlFile

Comment: I think I should create yaml file for deployement and I did it.

Comment: Yes, that's what i explained in the answer. 
Refer to this: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/